# VirtualHost setup for multi site on shared hosting

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore

In a shared hosting environment, I want to setup a multi site with both sites pointing to the same domain under different folders, i.e. `mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com/ws2`.

I have followed [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) tutorial.

Unfortunately I can't create a `VirtualHost` because I don't have access to Apache configuration file. The hosting support has told me that I can use a functionality called [Parked Domains](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains), but that doesn't accept folders under the same domain.

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there is what's called "Secondary Domains" which actually create a virtual host record form the shared hosting account's control panel. This is how Nexess shared Magento hosting works. If you're host doesn't support real virtual hosts, I would find a new hosting provider or get a second account for the second site, assuming they aren't running on the same base.

Edit: One thing else to consider... An actual virtual host is required to have an SSL setup on both domains. It's not possible with anything else because each one requires a dedicated IP for SSL negotiation.